# Display 1 result per Booking ID if Response Date is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is what part of my table looks like.

```
Response Date               Booking ID   Supplier  CSAT    Customer Effort
2017-02-18 14:00:00.000     76579481     NULL      77.00    2.00      
2017-02-18 14:00:00.000     76579481     NULL      77.00    2.00         
2017-02-18 14:00:00.000     76579481     NULL      77.00    2.00    
2017-02-18 14:00:00.000     76579481     NULL      77.00    2.00
```

As you can see, the above data (records of customer survey results) are duplicates, as a row is created each time a customer contacts us. I want to display only 1 row per Booking ID if Response Date is the same, as these records are duplicates but the records with different response dates are valid, as a customer can complete survey results multiple times, but cannot do this on the same date. The following is my query.

```
SELECT
        cx.review_date                            AS [Response Date],
        cx.fk_reservation                         AS [Booking ID],
        ca.company_name                           AS [Supplier],
        CAST(AVG(cx.csat_score) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [CSAT],
        CAST(AVG(cx.ces_score) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))  AS [Customer Effort],
        nps_score,
        CC.comments                               AS [Customer Feedback],
        rr.Country_ID                             AS [Pickup Country],
        rr.citizen_country_code                   AS Residency,
        cx.location_name                          AS [Pick-up Location],
        contractInfo.businessType                 AS [Business],
        G.LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD                        AS [Contact Date],
        G.BUSINESS_RESULT                         AS [Contact Reason],
        G.MEDIA_NAME                              AS [Contact Type],
        cl.Client_Name                            AS [Partner],
        cx.staff_id
FROM
        [Koios].[dbo].CCE_CXReview_Data               cx WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
    LEFT JOIN
        reservation_reporting                         AS rr WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON rr.Ref = cx.fk_reservation
    LEFT JOIN
        Car_Agents                                    AS ca WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON ca.car_agent_id = cx.car_agent_id
    LEFT JOIN
        Client                                        cl WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON cx.parent_id = cl.parent_id
    LEFT JOIN
        reservation_contract_info                     contractInfo WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON contractInfo.fk_reservation = rr.ref
    LEFT JOIN
        CX_Customer_Comments                          CC WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON CC.fk_reservation = cx.fk_reservation
    LEFT JOIN
        [Genesys].[dbo].[VA_Genesys]                  G WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON G.CASE_ID = rr.Reservation_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        [Genesys].[dbo].EXP_INTERACTION_RESOURCE_FACT I WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON I.INTERACTION_RESOURCE_ID = G.INTERACTION_RESOURCE_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        [Genesys].[dbo].EXP_DATE_TIME                 D WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON I.START_DATE_TIME_KEY = D.DATE_TIME_KEY
WHERE
        rr.reservation_status <> '4'
        AND rr.Dropoff_date
        BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31'
GROUP BY
        cx.review_date,
        ca.company_name,
        cx.fk_reservation,
        rr.Country_ID,
        rr.citizen_country_code,
        cx.location_name,
        CC.comments,
        contractInfo.businessType,
        G.LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD,
        G.BUSINESS_RESULT,
        G.MEDIA_NAME,
        cl.Client_Name,
        nps_score,
        cx.staff_id;
```

I have had no luck with this so far. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Does adding `distinct` to the query help? Maybe a quick workaround?

Comment: Hey. I have tried adding distinct and it doesn't seem to work for me at all. The query runs and displays the same duplicate results.

Comment: You said "on the same date" yet your small sample clearly shows that your datatype includes time. Do you really mean "date" or do you mean the "exact same datetime value"?  Next - using hints is not some "turbo" option that has no consequences. Do you understand those consequences? Lastly you left join to alias rr yet you refer to it in the where clause - turning that left join into an inner join.

Comment: And I suggest you simplify your query in order to find a solution. Get rid of all the joins and concentrate on the cx table/view for now. Most likely you can use row_number to get a single row per booking_id and datetime value - but you will need to determine what logic to use in order to pick just one row. So - what logic do you propose? And are you assuming that "it doesn't matter" since your sample data just **happens** to have the same or similar values in the other columns? Be very careful of your assumptions and your test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that i see is your are putting too many columns inside the GroupBy

try something like this

```
SELECT
    cx.review_date                            AS [Response Date],
    cx.fk_reservation                         AS [Booking ID],
    MAX(ca.company_name)                           AS [Supplier],
    CAST(AVG(cx.csat_score) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [CSAT],
    CAST(AVG(cx.ces_score) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))  AS [Customer Effort],
    MAX(nps_score),
    MAX(CC.comments)                               AS [Customer Feedback],
    MAX(rr.Country_ID)                             AS [Pickup Country],
    MAX(rr.citizen_country_code)                   AS Residency,
    MAX(cx.location_name)                          AS [Pick-up Location],
    MAX(contractInfo.businessType)                 AS [Business],
    MAX(G.LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD)                        AS [Contact Date],
    MAX(G.BUSINESS_RESULT)                         AS [Contact Reason],
    MAX(G.MEDIA_NAME)                              AS [Contact Type],
    MAX(cl.Client_Name)                            AS [Partner],
    MAX(cx.staff_id)
FROM
        [Koios].[dbo].CCE_CXReview_Data               cx WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
    LEFT JOIN
        reservation_reporting                         AS rr WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON rr.Ref = cx.fk_reservation
    LEFT JOIN
        Car_Agents                                    AS ca WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON ca.car_agent_id = cx.car_agent_id
    LEFT JOIN
        Client                                        cl WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON cx.parent_id = cl.parent_id
    LEFT JOIN
        reservation_contract_info                     contractInfo WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON contractInfo.fk_reservation = rr.ref
    LEFT JOIN
        CX_Customer_Comments                          CC WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON CC.fk_reservation = cx.fk_reservation
    LEFT JOIN
        [Genesys].[dbo].[VA_Genesys]                  G WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON G.CASE_ID = rr.Reservation_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        [Genesys].[dbo].EXP_INTERACTION_RESOURCE_FACT I WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON I.INTERACTION_RESOURCE_ID = G.INTERACTION_RESOURCE_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        [Genesys].[dbo].EXP_DATE_TIME                 D WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
            ON I.START_DATE_TIME_KEY = D.DATE_TIME_KEY
WHERE
        rr.reservation_status <> '4'
        AND rr.Dropoff_date
        BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31'
GROUP BY
        cx.review_date,
        cx.fk_reservation;
```

Comment: Hi. Your improvements removed the duplicates rows correctly. However, the results pulled from the query were missing quite a lot of records from the database, so I re-wrote the query using your improvements (Using aggregate functions instead of adding each column to the group by clause) and this time joined the tables in the correct order and it's now pulling exactly what I was looking for. Thanks you very much, your response was very helpful!